# Win 2008 - certificate renewing - I can't choose proper CA

Tags: certificate-authority, renew

I've got a problem with renewing server certificate:

when I get to the IIS Manager => Server Certificates and when I try to renew right certificate, I can't find proper CA on the list - theres only Win 2012 machine and there should be also Win 2008.
[Just take a look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjj7W.gif)

On the other hand, after typing `certutil -config - -ping` on the Win 2008 machine, I get back both of CA's - and both of them are alive. 
And when I try to do the same command (`certutil -config - -ping`) on any other machine in LAN, theres only Win 2012 showed.

Can anybody help me to solve that, please?

Comment: it looks like your Win2008 machine is Standalone CA.

Comment: The problem is, I can't renew certificate which is used to authenticate users logging by smart cards to system (now I have to log them by login/password). Till yesterday, everything worked fine, but after that certificate expired, I can't renew it to use it again.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow, when I'll get back to work, but I think it's Enterprise CA and something was just messed up.

Comment: @CryptoGuy - Yeah, I just typed `certutil -getreg ca\catype` - the result is `ENUM_ENTERPRISE_ROOTCA`...

Comment: It appears that your Windows Server 2008 CA is lost its registration in Active Directory. In the ADSIEdit check the following container: `CN=Enrollment Services, CN=Public Key Services, CN=Services {Configuration naming context}`. Does it have entry for your CA?

Comment: @CryptoGuy - Hmm, there's something weird I think, because I've found an entry for my CA there, but in the `dNSHostName`, is an entry of Win2012 server. Shouldn't it be 2k8 instead? Can I just safely change it by pressing Edit button?

Comment: Yes, there should be win2k8 server DNS name.

Comment: I did changed the DNS hostname, and now I can select the proper CA from the Server Certificates list, but after I click on Finish it gives me the following message: "The certificate request was submitted to the online authority but was not issued. The request was denied"

Comment: Start new thread for this question.